# When husband/he checked his wife mobile

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which of the following sentence is grammatically correct?

> 1. When *husband/he* checked **his** wife mobile.
> 2. When *husband/he* checked **her** wife mobile.

Comment: Neither is grammatical as written.  You really should wait to accept an answer until you get more feedback.  In addition, please edit your question to explain why you find this grammar confusing, otherwise it may be closed as *proofreading*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Wife is, of course, **his** wife. So when he checked her mobile, he checked **his** wife mobile.

Comment: It's a bad idea to simply answer a question without addressing its multiple grammatical errors.  Moreover the question should have included more detail to explain why this grammar is confusing, otherwise it's just proofreading.

Comment: @Andrew: If a question Needs More Details, there's no need to call it proofreading, especially when there is no intent to look for proofreading. A question that puts specific emphasis on particular words, but doesn't explain the potential problem or confusion, may indeed need to be closed until this is clarified, but the reason has nothing to do with proofreading, and calling it such is a confusing misuse of the close reason.